# Need to handle click from NON-Activity( .java ) class

Tags: java, android

i have one main Activity class which contains huge amount of code/data. So i want to make it short and readable so i want to create one .java file which handle the some functionality as per the requirement. Like

```
Button b=(Button)findviewById(R.id.b1);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and Show a Toast from non-activity class.
So my question is How to handle/initialize button in non-activity?
Can we get id's from Passing Context from Activity to non-activity class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this is **working for me** . May help you also !

**NonActivityClass:**

```
public class NonActivityClass {

    Context context;
    View v;
    public NonActivityClass(Context context, View v) {
        this.context = context;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public void test() {
        Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello I am inside Non Activity Class",
                        1).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(v);
        NonActivityClass nac = new NonActivityClass(MainActivity.this, v);
        nac.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by implementing OnClickListener in your other java class and call this in you activity class for this do like this

```
Button b=(Button)findviewById(R.id.b1);
b.setOnClickListener(new NonActivityClass(this));
```

We are passing activity context to NonActivityClass this will make you access your UI component in NonActivityClass but **keep in mind this may lead to memory leak**;

And implement OnClickListener like :

```
public class NonActivityClass implements OnClickListener 
{
    void onClick(View oView)
    {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement your onclick listener in your main class BUT use an interface to externalise the content of the listener in an other Class.

**Exemple :**

Create a class ManageClick.java that contain constructor, several methods and objects.

An attribute

```
public OnClickListenerCustom _onClickListenerCustom;
```

And an interface

```
Interface OnClickListenerCustom{
    public void onclick();
    public void onItemClick();
}
```

and another method like setOnClickListenerCustom :

```
public void setOnClickListenerCustom(OnClickListenerCustom listener){
    this._onClickListenerCustom = listener;
}
```

In your main Class MainActivity.java you implement the onclick() method, in the oncreate you set the listener :

```
public ManageClick _clickManager;

_clickManager = new ManageClick();
_clickManager.setOnClickListener((OnClickListenerCustom) this.MainActivity);
```

To finish in the onclick method you only need to call

```
_clickManager.onClick() or _clickManager.onItemClick()
```