# Android Button click Listener in another Non Activity Class

Tags: android, button, callback, onclick

Here is class implementing `public class Myclass implements View.OnClickListener {
}` 
Here is constructor passing reference to required buttons

```
public class Myclass implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Myclass(){
        check_out_final = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.check_out_final);
        check_out = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.check_out);

        if(context instanceof View.OnClickListener){
            check_out_final.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);
            check_out.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CheckOutActivity.class));
    }
}
```

All fine, Button is being referenced but onClick is not working

Comment: Give more information!!

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567762/need-to-handle-click-from-non-activity-java-class).

Comment: @AkashPatel I am just passing context to this NON activity class. Not View

Comment: show your activity too.

Comment: @AkashPatel `new Myclass(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code

```
if(context instanceof View.OnClickListener){
    check_out_final.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);
    check_out.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);
    }
```

with this

```
check_out_final.setOnClickListener(this);
check_out.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: `this` is not accessible inside non activity class

Comment: you can pass the context to the necessary class and achieve the click listener

Comment: @Usman just for clarification can u tell me did u try with "this" already?

Comment: @Raghavendra I thinks I have mentioned necessary code.

Comment: @JijuInduchoodan I am using same technique but `view.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListenercontext) context)` is not being referenced

Comment: Can you debug and confirm whether the click is getting invoked on the onClick method